# In multilevel columns pandas dataframe, reorder the specific lower level of categories

Tags: python, pandas

I got a multilevel dataframe with the multivel columns, df.columns is

```
ultiIndex([(   'county',                                          ''),
        (    'month',                                          ''),
        (   'Gender',                 'Declined to self-identify'),
        (   'Gender',                                    'Female'),
        (   'Gender',                                      'Male'),
        (   'Gender',             'Non-Binary / Gender expansive'),
        (      'age',                                       '0-4'),
        (      'age',                                     '11-13'),
        (      'age',                                     '15-18'),
        (      'age',                                     '19-24'),
        (      'age',                                     '25-34'),
        (      'age',                                     '35-44'),
        (      'age',                                     '45-54'),
        (      'age',                                      '5-10'),
        (      'age',                                     '55-64'),
        (      'age',                                   '65_vove'),
        (      'age',                                    'Unkown'),
        (     'race',          'American Indian or Alaska Native'),
        (     'race',                                     'Asian'),
        (     'race',                 'Black or African American'),
        (     'race', 'Native Hawaiian or other Pacific Islander'),
        (     'race',                                   'UNKnown'),
        (     'race',                                     'White'),
        ('Ethnicity',                        'Hispanic or Latinx'),
        ('Ethnicity',                    'Non Hispanic or Latinx'),
        ('Ethnicity',                                   'Unknown')],
       names=['variable', 'value'])
```

I would like to reorder the race as

```
race_order = ['Black or African American', 'American Indian or Alaska Native','Asian',
              'Native Hawaiian or other Pacific Islander','White', 'UNKnown']
```

Comment: I just realized there was a typo in my answer, if you want a real sorting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example Code**

let's make sample input

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = [('county', ''), ('month', ''), ('Gender', 'Declined to self-identify'), ('Gender', 'Female'), ('Gender', 'Male'), ('Gender', 'Non-Binary / Gender expansive'), ('age', '0-4'), ('age', '11-13'), ('age', '15-18'), ('age', '19-24'), ('age', '25-34'), ('age', '35-44'), ('age', '45-54'), ('age', '5-10'), ('age', '55-64'), ('age', '65_vove'), ('age', 'Unkown'), ('race', 'American Indian or Alaska Native'), ('race', 'Asian'), ('race', 'Black or African American'), ('race', 'Native Hawaiian or other Pacific Islander'), ('race', 'UNKnown'), ('race', 'White'), ('Ethnicity', 'Hispanic or Latinx'), ('Ethnicity', 'Non Hispanic or Latinx'), ('Ethnicity', 'Unknown')]

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 26)), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(a,  names=['variable', 'value']))
```

df:

[image]

---

```
df1 = df.columns.to_frame(index=False)
race_order = ['Black or African American', 'American Indian or Alaska Native','Asian', 'Native Hawaiian or other Pacific Islander','White', 'UNKnown']
df1.loc[df1['variable'].eq('race'), 'value'] = race_order
out = df[pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1, names=['variable', 'value'])]
```

out:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `idx` your original MultiIndex, you could use a temporary DataFrame to perform a sort on a slice:

```
tmp = idx.to_frame(index=False)
m = tmp['variable'].eq('race')
key = pd.Series(range(len(race_order)), index=race_order).get
tmp[m] = tmp[m].sort_values(by='value', key=key).values

new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(tmp)
```

Output:

```
MultiIndex([(   'county',                                          ''),
            (    'month',                                          ''),
            (   'Gender',                 'Declined to self-identify'),
            (   'Gender',                                    'Female'),
            (   'Gender',                                      'Male'),
            (   'Gender',             'Non-Binary / Gender expansive'),
            (      'age',                                       '0-4'),
            (      'age',                                     '11-13'),
            (      'age',                                     '15-18'),
            (      'age',                                     '19-24'),
            (      'age',                                     '25-34'),
            (      'age',                                     '35-44'),
            (      'age',                                     '45-54'),
            (      'age',                                      '5-10'),
            (      'age',                                     '55-64'),
            (      'age',                                   '65_vove'),
            (      'age',                                    'Unkown'),
            (     'race',                 'Black or African American'),
            (     'race',          'American Indian or Alaska Native'),
            (     'race',                                     'Asian'),
            (     'race', 'Native Hawaiian or other Pacific Islander'),
            (     'race',                                     'White'),
            (     'race',                                   'UNKnown'),
            ('Ethnicity',                        'Hispanic or Latinx'),
            ('Ethnicity',                    'Non Hispanic or Latinx'),
            ('Ethnicity',                                   'Unknown')],
           names=['variable', 'value'])
```